# Create column with some values from another columns - Conditional

Tags: python, pandas, np

I have a column Values that contain the category examples: New Va,P Va,B... I need to create one column for each category and your respective value

```
       Date  Column1 Total        Type Values
0       NaN      NaN   NaN       Type1    5.1
1       NaN  Column2   Sum       Type1 New Va
2   04/2019        2   NaN       Type1    NaN
3   05/2019        2   NaN       Type1    NaN
4   06/2019        2     2       Type1     14
5   07/2019        4     4       Type1     16
6       NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN
7       NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 4   P Va
8   04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN
9   05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN
10  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 4     10
11  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 4     15
12      NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN
13      NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 5      B
14  04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN
15  05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN
16  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 5      8
17  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 5      7
18      NaN      NaN   NaN       Type2    4.9
```

Considering that NAN Data values from Date column will be removed, the expected result is:

```
       Date  Column1 Total        Type Values New Va   P Va  B
0       NaN      NaN   NaN       Type1    5.1   
1       NaN  Column2   Sum       Type1      N
2   04/2019        2   NaN       Type1    NaN   0
3   05/2019        2   NaN       Type1    NaN   0
4   06/2019        2     2       Type1     14   14
5   07/2019        4     4       Type1     16   16
6       NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN
7       NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 4      P
8   04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN       0
9   05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4    NaN       0
10  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 4     10       10
11  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 4     15       15
12      NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN
13      NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 5      B            
14  04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN              0
15  05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5    NaN              0
16  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 5      8              8
17  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 5      7              7
18      NaN      NaN   NaN       Type2    4.9
```

After that, I will group by the values from Date to keep the values New Pa, P Va, and B in the same row.
I'm trying to use the for to create new columns identifying the

```
 df['New Va'] = np.where(df['Values'].str.contains('New Va'),'N',np.NaN)
```

However, all lines differents from P and B are  NaN, and I don't have the numbers like example above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re  # Not strictly necessary, but it might speed things up for lots of data

pat = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z\s]*$")            # compile is what might speed things up
v = df.Values[df.Column1.notna()].fillna(0) 
a = ~v.str.match(pat).fillna(False)          # mask of things that don't match
keys = pd.unique(v[~a])                      # get unique matches
fill = dict.fromkeys(keys, '')
d = pd.get_dummies(v.mask(a).ffill())[a]
new = d.mul(pd.to_numeric(v[a]), axis=0).where(d == 1, '')[keys]

df.join(new).fillna(fill)

       Date  Column1 Total        Type  Values New Va P Va  B
0       NaN      NaN   NaN       Type1     5.1               
1       NaN  Column2   Sum       Type1  New Va               
2   04/2019        2   NaN       Type1     NaN      0        
3   05/2019        2   NaN       Type1     NaN      0        
4   06/2019        2     2       Type1      14     14        
5   07/2019        4     4       Type1      16     16        
6       NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN               
7       NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 4    P Va               
8   04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN           0   
9   05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN           0   
10  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 4      10          10   
11  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 4      15          15   
12      NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN               
13      NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 5       B               
14  04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN              0
15  05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN              0
16  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 5       8              8
17  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 5       7              7
18      NaN      NaN   NaN       Type2     4.9
```

Comment: Nice answer @piRSquared :)

Comment: Your alternate approach is almost there. How can I verify if has alpha and with spaces? I'm trying to use 
keys = pd.unique([s for s in s if str(s).isalpha() or str(s).isspace()])
But this not working...

Comment: @Twwister8889 include it in your example so that I understand

Comment: @piRSquared I edited, included the 'New Va' as a category
My code I have:
keys = pd.unique([s for s in s if str(s).replace(' ','').isalpha()])      -- I don't know if is the best way, but its working
But the problem now, its here:
a = ~v.str.isalpha().fillna(False)
Here contains string with space

Comment: @Twwister8889 I understand now. I can include that later when I get home

Comment: OK, thank you so much, I'm sorry, but this scenario occours now, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let us try:

```
m = df['Values'].str.contains(r'(?i)^[A-Z\s]+$', na=False)
c, b = list(df.loc[m, 'Values']), m.cumsum()

for _, v in df['Values'].groupby(b):
    if v.iat[0] in c:
        s = v.iloc[1:].fillna(0)
        df.loc[s.index, v.iat[0]] = s

df[c] = df[c].mask(df['Date'].isna()).fillna('')
```

**Details:**

Create a boolean mask with `str.contains` specifying the condition where `Values` contain `Categories` like `New Va`, `P Va`, `B`:

```
>>> m
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13     True
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18    False
Name: Values, dtype: bool
```

Identify the blocks starting with category in the `Values` columns:

```
>>> b

0     0
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    2
12    2
13    3
14    3
15    3
16    3
17    3
18    3
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

Group the column `Values` on this blocks of elements and for each group add/update the category column in the dataframe with the values that follows the category in each block, finally `mask` the values in these newly added column where `Date` is `NaN`:

```
>>> df

       Date  Column1 Total        Type  Values New Va P Va  B
0       NaN      NaN   NaN       Type1     5.1               
1       NaN  Column2   Sum       Type1  New Va               
2   04/2019        2   NaN       Type1     NaN      0        
3   05/2019        2   NaN       Type1     NaN      0        
4   06/2019        2     2       Type1      14     14        
5   07/2019        4     4       Type1      16     16        
6       NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN               
7       NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 4    P Va               
8   04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN           0   
9   05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 4     NaN           0   
10  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 4      10          10   
11  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 4      15          15   
12      NaN      NaN   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN               
13      NaN  Column2   Sum  Unnamed: 5       B               
14  04/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN              0
15  05/2019        2   NaN  Unnamed: 5     NaN              0
16  06/2019        2     2  Unnamed: 5       8              8
17  07/2019        4     4  Unnamed: 5       7              7
18      NaN      NaN   NaN       Type2     4.9
```

Comment: The problem is: I will have one more row for other months for the N, P, and B category, so the result shows just the last occurs this values. In my dataset, the first occurs for N 0,0,14 and 16 is missing only the last values is showing, How can I solve this? Thanks